# regex between two special characters

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Is there a way to replicate this PHP snippet in JQuery or Javascript...

```
<?php 
  $A = preg_match_all('#{.*(.*)}#U', $value, $B); //matches all between {} put it into array "B"
  $C = $B[1]; // array[0] = "{content}" --- array[1] = "content"
?>
```

I have been trying to find something similar for like 4 hours or so to no avail.
The goal is basically to find everything between `{` and `}` and then pull that information out to be useful.

I am no Javascript expert so I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get all blocks of text between { and } into an array with this:

```
function getBracedText(input) {
    var re = /\{(.*?)\}/g, matches, output = [];
    while (matches = re.exec(input)) {
        output.push(matches[1]);
    }
    return(output);
}

var str = "Some text {tag} and more {text}";
var results = getBracedText(str);
// results == ["tag", "text"];
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/DT4Km/

Comment: But wait, this is not browser compatible. It quirks in mozilla

Comment: @JuanGonzales - Seems to work fine for me in Firefox in my jsFiddle.  What exactly are you seeing and in what browser?  This is standard use of `.exec()` as documented on [Mozilla's MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

Comment: Never mind. The error is coming from another area of code. I am getting the contents from an iframe and cross referencing the contents, but in FF it seems to be adding an extra span tag and div to my markup... causing the error. You wouldn't know how to handle this would you?

Comment: It's also doing that in IE as well

Comment: @JuanGonzales - I'd be happy to help with this other problem, but you'd have to show the relevant code/html for me to even understand the situation.

Comment: @jfriend00 I just posted a new question here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406261/iframe-is-adding-tags-need-to-remove-them

Answer (score 2):

Regex are pretty much the same across all languages. If you want to get everything in between `{}` and put it into an array you can do this:

```
var arr = [];
var str = 'Lorem {ipsum dolor} sit {amet} conseteur {adipisci}';
str.replace(/{(.+?)}/g, function(a, b){ arr.push(b) });

console.log(arr); //=> ["ipsum dolor", "amet", "adipisci"]
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/xeHZn/

Answer (score 0):

This expression should work fine:

```
/{([^}]+)}/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do:

```
 var re = /{[^}]*}/g;
 var s = '{foo},bar,{fum}';

 alert(s.match(re)); // ['{foo}','{fum}']
```

but you may not want the "{}" included.

```
var re = /{([^}]*)}/g;
var s = '{foo},bar,{fum}';

var a = [];
var b;
while (b = re.exec(s)) {
  a.push(b[1]);
}

alert(a); // ['foo','fum'];
```

There's bound to be a way to do it with a single regular expression and no loop.

Comment: @jfriend00. You can do it with `replace` too, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
var value = "some {example}";
value.match(/{([^}]+)}/); //array[0] = "{example}" --- array[1] = "example"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = '{Some groovy text}not so groovy text';
var regex = /\{(.*?)\}/;
var value = str.match(regex)[1];  // 'Some groovy text';
```

This will retrieve the content within the brackets. Hope this helps.