# iframe is adding tags, need to remove them

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to get the contents of an iframe (converted to a simple rich text editor) and then modify those contents using jquery, but I am running into problems because in IE and in FF when I get the content it adds an extra span tag and div tag with stylings. How can I remove these tags/styles.

This is how Im getting the contents...

```
var frame = window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML; /////Gets contents of iframe
$("#songRes").html(frame); /////Places info into proper div
```

Im trying to find out if the first char is a '{' and if so then do something

```
var frame = window.frames['richTextField'].document.body.innerHTML; /////Gets contents of iframe
  adj = frame.replace(/<div>/gi,"<br \/>").replace(/<\/div>/gi,""); /////String replaces contents of frame
  $("#songRes").html(adj+'<hr />'); /////Places info into proper div
  var array = adj.split("<br />"); /////Splits each line into array values
  var array = frame.split("<br />");
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    var str = array[i];
    if(str.charAt( 0 ) != '{'){/**/}else{/**/} // 
  }
```

But the problem is that the it shows the starting char as '<' from the span tag that I didn't add.

Comment: How are you retrieving the `str` variable?

Comment: You should post an example showing the iframe contents and the tags/styles you want to remove

Comment: Try `.innerText` instead of `innerHTML`.

Comment: @IliaFrenkel .innerText didn't work.

Comment: Are you using some kind of javascript reach text editor (like TinyMCE)? If so, it should have a method to get the text. Can you post some more details?

Comment: I just updated my code to show more info. I am using my own simple rich text. It's light weight because I am using is bold, italics, and underline. The only execCommands are those that correspond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an AMAZING website that basically rewrites php code for javascript. I used the strip_tags function from there. Check it out...

```
function strip_tags (input, allowed) {
    allowed = (((allowed || "") + "").toLowerCase().match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || []).join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
    var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
        commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
    return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function ($0, $1) {
        return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
    });
}
```

Found it at... [phpjs.org](http://www.phpjs.org)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why `.innerText` didn't work (maybe because you are using Firefox). Anyhow, here is another suggestion:

```
function strip(html)
{
   var tmp = document.createElement("DIV");
   tmp.innerHTML = html;
   return tmp.textContent||tmp.innerText;
}
```

This was an accepted answer to this [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript) question.